# GET SQL data from table as JSON into Bootstrap Table script

Tags: php, json, pdo, datatable

Due to some function like Excel and PDF download i want to implement some script on my site. I have found a solution at bootstrap-table.com I failed to retrieve the table data as they are a json source (data-url) in the script. My data for the table are available in a SQL database. I have tried to create a query and create a output in json format but i failed. I a m asking for help on this point.

This is the base code i have found:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>

<style>
#toolbar {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="toolbar" class="select">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Export Basic</option>
    <option value="all">Export All</option>
    <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table id="table"
  data-show-export="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-click-to-select="true"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data">
</table>

<script>
  var $table = $('#table')

  $(function() {
    $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
      $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
        exportDataType: $(this).val(),
        exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        columns: [
          {
            field: 'state',
            checkbox: true,
            visible: $(this).val() === 'selected'
          },
          {
            field: 'id',
            title: 'ID'
          }, {
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Item Name'
          }, {
            field: 'price',
            title: 'Item Price'
          }
        ]
      })
    }).trigger('change')
  })
</script>
```

My problem is as explained that my data are available in my SQL database. So i retrieve my data like:

```html
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, vorname, rolle FROM users WHERE cid = :cid");
$result = $statement->execute(array(':cid' => $user['cid']));
$users = $statement->fetch();
```

I thought to change the data-url from this `data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data"` to this `data-url="<?=json_encode($users)?>` will work but i get no data shown in my table.

Any idea to get this working correctly by using my PDO Query?

Comment: Compare the result and structure of what you get from `json_encode($users)` with what the data at https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data looks like, and then adjust your PHP accordingly to make it output the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive this would soulve your problem, first of all set the headers for your page as json, this should come before any output on the page:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Then fetch your users just like you normally would.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, vorname, rolle FROM users WHERE cid = :cid");
$result = $statement->execute(array(':cid' => $user['cid']));
$users = $statement->fetch();
```

And finnaly echo that result:

```
echo $users
```

So in summary, your script should look like this:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

   $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, vorname, rolle FROM users WHERE cid = :cid");
   $result = $statement->execute(array(':cid' => $user['cid']));
   $users = $statement->fetch();

   echo json_encode($users);
?>
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Create a new PHP file, with the content in the code above, i dont know how your URL is structured, but you should be able to access this file via a url for example `http://yoursite.com/users/jsondata`, if you need to pass parameters to alter the result you could use query parameter for instance `http://yoursite.com/users/jsondata?minprice=2&maxprice=10`, and alter your data accordingly.
When you visit this url you should be able to to see your data structured similarly to what you have here: https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data

Then in your table you can have:

```
<table id="table"
  ...
  data-url="http://yoursite.com/users/jsondata<?=($_GET['minprice'] ? '?minprice=' . $_GET['minprice'] : '').($_GET['maxprice'] ? '&maxprice=' . $_GET['maxprice'] : '')?>">
</table>
```

There's actually a whole lot more you could do to make your code even more elegant but this should give you a head start.

**EDIT**

After looking at the example link you provided, I had to come up with this.

```
$users = $statement->fetch();
$data = [
   'total' => count($users),
   'totalNotFiltered' => count($users),
   'rows' => $users,
];
echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: `first of all set the headers for your page as json`...that would make sense, except that the code you've written won't output JSON. In fact most likely it'll produce a warning about trying to convert an array to a string. Did you forget the `json_encode` part? Also, this won't create JSON in the same structure as the JSON the OP is trying to replace, so it probably won't be acceptable to the bootsrap plugin they're trying to feed it to.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry I missed that part, I have edited my answer, can you give me back my up vote?

Comment: If i set the header i will get a output of the json data on my website instead of the table.

Comment: @3m1n3n3 the output format is still going to be wrong, though. Check out the JSON in the link the OP linked to

Comment: @MischaMustermann Put the script that will generate the json on a separate page then provide a link to that page in your `data-url`

Comment: @MischaMustermann well if you access the URL directly you'd get that, but if you make it as the data-url of the table that wouldn't happen

Comment: Yes i know, my query output is not in Json formated. even if i use **json_encode(['rows' => $results]**. I think thats the reason why its not working. I f i use the same script on a different site and use the header and include it as the source, it works. But this doesnt solve my problem because the query is then static. I really struggle here...

Comment: the specific page i made is giving the user the possibiliy to make some personal data evaluations. He can select filter values. Those selections by the user i take and change the query. So if i have the Json query on a different site it wont work anymore.

Comment: @MischaMustermann It's not clear what you mean. As mentioned, you need to put this PHP query code into a separate .php script file on your server, and make the URL of that file as your data-url. Then it'll be called every time the table needs data, and will run the query each time.

Comment: @MischaMustermann nobody mentioned putting it on a separate _site_, we simply said to move the PHP code to another file! Then it won't interfere with loading your HTML.

Comment: Understoof, the PHP code is including the PDO query which generates the results (rows). But my query changes based on the users selection. So how to get those selections into the seperate  PHP file.

Comment: @MischaMustermann you would need to send them as parameters in the request. I don't know the specific plugin you're talking about, you'd need to link us to some documentation, but I'd guess it probably has a way to allow you to customise the content of what's sent to the data URL

Comment: @MischaMustermann You could pass the user's selection and preference via url query parameters and handle those parameters in the file where the json data will be generated.

Comment: i am using this Bootstrap table plugin. I need the export function. In the documentation there is no example with "standard HTML Tables" with export function. Seems like the export is feeded by the Json data. 
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/export.html So i cant use for example this one, which would make everything easier. https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#welcomes/from-html.html#view-source

Comment: @MischaMustermann I have updated my answer one last time, look at the section I marked FINAL EDIT. If you don't get it, forget about it.

Comment: @3m1n3n3 well i have tried it now with several methods but the only one which is working is to pass the data as you proposed in a URL and let the script run on a separate site like json_data.php and make this site as source (data-url). Seems like that this script needs clear Json format with the right header and does not work with from a SQL query encoded Json result. If i have time i will ask the Bootstrap support but i can live with your method as well. As i pass the requested data in the data-url´s URL i dont see a risk in SQL injection for the moment. Thank you for your help <3

Comment: @MischaMustermann if my answer solved your problem, please do well to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MischaMustermann `clear Json format with the right header and does not work with from a SQL query encoded Json` this doesn't make sense. The bootstrap table has no way of knowing whether the JSON was static text or generated or from a SQL query - it just sees the finished JSON. But if you're saying it doesn't work when directly embedded in your page as the data-url, or you're saying it doesn't work if you don't use the same JSON structure as in the hard-coded version, then that would make sense. Don't conflate different issues.

Comment: @MischaMustermann `As i pass the requested data in the data-url´s URL i dont see a risk in SQL injection`...this doesn't make sense either. So your data-url is static in your page? Ok but that doesn't prevent someone from going into the HTML source code (using the browser's Developer Tools) and editing the URL. It also doesn't prevent someone from making a completely independent request to the same URL by pasting it into their browser, or using Postman, or writing a script. The only way to prevent SQL injection is to use parameterised queries, but you've already done that so you're safe anyway